# How to center a view loaded from nib file?

Tags: ios, view, alignment, nib

I have a view defined in a nib file. (named `FooView.xib`)

The view is of a fixed size (smaller than screen size).

I would like to load it in a view controller (named `FooViewController.[hm]`) and I want the view to show up in the center of the screen in whatever devices (a universal app).

Since the name of the xib and viewcontroller class have such correspondence, the view in the xib is loaded automatically.

Then I write code in the `-(void)viewDidLoad` method to center my view, which can be referenced by `self.view`. I write something like this.

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
self.view.center = CGPointMake(screenBounds.size.width/2, screenBounds.size.height/2);
```

And it does not work. Neither will it work when I modify `self.view.frame = ...`.

I checked the values of `self.view.center` or `self.view.frame`. They did change but I didn't see any changes in the simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the xib file make sure you have disabled auto-layout.

in viewController.m: (*Edit: place this in viewDidAppear not in viewDidLoad)

```
[self.view addSubview:myView];
myView.center = self.view.center;
```

Comment: Place it in ViewDidAppear ... ViewDidLoad has not yet updated the view size depending on wether or not you are in an iPhone5 sized screen or an iPhone4- sized screen.

Comment: You don't need to use CGMakePoint, just myView.center = self.view.center